# .zIndex() only applying to sibling views inside VStack but not to views outside

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

This is the layout I have:

```
VStack {
 Image()
 
 HStack { 
   
   Image()

   VStack {
     CustomDropdown() //expands views till bottom of screen
       .zIndex(1)
 
     AnotherView()
   }

 }

 MyButton()

}
```

As you can see, I need my `CustomDropdown` to overlap all views below it on the screen, thus I set it's `zIndex` to 1.

**The Issue:**

The `CustomDropdown` is only overlapping it's sibling views below it that share the same `VStack`. However it's able to overlap the bottom `MyButton` since they are not sharing the same `VStack`.

I tried setting the `MyButton`s index to 0 but of course that took no affect.

I am fresh in `SwiftUI` and I am sure I am missing a simple solution to this task.

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:**

**My objective is to find a way such that the dropDown view will be able to handle the Z logic without help from Views around it I.E setting the Z index of other views in the screen**

Comment: It is wrong expectation, `zIndex` behaves as it should - changes default order of subviews within parent view. (Actually the same as in UIKit).

Comment: @Asperi I understand that. my question is: what is indeed the correct way to apply it above all views in screen. I want to avoid applying `ZStack` since i want the `CustomDropdown` to handle this logic for reusability purposes

Answer (score 3):

Your current view hierarchy has 3 "top-level" elements:

```
Image
HStack
MyButton
```

So, to get anything contained inside the `HStack` to be "on-top-of" `MyButton` (or any other following elements), you have to raise the z-index of ***HStack***.

Here's a simple example - tapping on the Green rectangle will toggle its Height between 80 and 300:

```
struct ExpandableView: View {
    @State var expanded = false

    var body: some View {
        VStack {

            // Red view
            Rectangle()
                .fill(Color.red)
                .frame(width: 300, height: 80, alignment: .top)
            
            HStack {
                
                // Green view (your CustomDropdown)
                Rectangle()
                    .fill(Color.green)
                    .frame(width: 100, height: expanded ? 300 : 80, alignment: .top)
                    .onTapGesture {
                        expanded.toggle()
                    }
                
            }
            .frame(width: 300, height: 120, alignment: .top)
            
            // Blue view (your MyButton)
            Rectangle()
                .fill(Color.blue)
                .frame(width: 200, height: 100, alignment: .top)
            
        }
        
    }

}
```

As you've experienced, this is the result:

[image] [image]

It doesn't matter what you do with the z-index of the Green view... it will only affect its hierarchy-order ***within*** the `HStack`.

But, if we modify the z-index of the **HStack**:

```
struct ExpandableView: View {
    @State var expanded = false

    var body: some View {
        VStack {

            // Red view
            Rectangle()
                .fill(Color.red)
                .frame(width: 300, height: 80, alignment: .top)
            
            HStack {
                
                // Green view (your CustomDropdown)
                Rectangle()
                    .fill(Color.green)
                    .frame(width: 100, height: expanded ? 300 : 80, alignment: .top)
                    .onTapGesture {
                        expanded.toggle()
                    }
                
            }
            .frame(width: 300, height: 120, alignment: .top)
            // bring HStack above following elements (Blue Rectangle)
            .zIndex(1)
            
            // Blue view (your MyButton)
            Rectangle()
                .fill(Color.blue)
                .frame(width: 200, height: 100, alignment: .top)
            
        }
        
    }

}
```

we get this:

[image] [image]

Comment: thanks for the effort and detailed response. to be frank that's what I ended up doing after exhausting other options. Though the objective of my question is: Is there a way for a view to set in itself it's own zIndex in such a way that the consumer won't need to care each time consuming the dropdown about the the Z relation with other views.. 

Hope, made myself clearer :)

[in any case thumbing up your answer for the effort]

Comment: @HudiIlfeld - I don't use SwiftUI, but I don't think there is a way to "walk up" the view hierarchy to manipulate the z-indexes. You may need to re-think your design and maybe use presented / popover / views or menus etc.